# Why doesn't input return a the print value with .lower() or .upper() commands?

Tags: python, string, input

When i run the code my python doesn't recognize what i put in whether it's with .lower or .upper, why is that?

```
import sys

Good = input('Am i Good? > ').upper()
if Good == 'no':
print(True, 'You are good')
elif Good == 'no':
print(True, ' You are still good')
elif Good == 'quit':
sys.exit()
```

Comment: because you convert it to upper then check against lower case strings?

Comment: Well, `.upper()` will give you an uppercase string, so it cannot possibly be equal to `'no'`. With a lowercase string, the comparisons will work as written - however, I notice that you have two comparisons to `'no'`. Did you perhaps intend for one of them to be `'yes'` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
Good = input('Am i Good? > ').upper()
```

You transform the input to uppercase, but then you compare the string with lowercase strings (`"no"`, `"quit"`). This will never match since `"NO"` and `"no"` are different strings (Python cares about case when comparing strings).